# keeping the apostrophe using the textcnt function from the tau package in R

Tags: r, regex, apostrophe

The textcnt function in R's tau package has a split argument and it's default value is
split = "[[:space:][:punct:][:digit:]]+" ç this argumet uses the apostrophe ' to split into words too and I don't want that, how can I modify the argument so it doesn't use the apostrophe to split words?

this code:

`library(tau)
text<-"I don't want the function to use the ' to split"

textcnt(text, split = "[[:space:][:punct:][:digit:]]+",method="string",n=1L)`

produces this output:

```
 don function        i    split        t      the       to      use     want 
   1        1        1        1        1        2        2        1        1
```

instead of having don 1 and t 1, i would like to keep don't as 1 word

I have tried to use str_replace_all from stringr to remove the punctuation beforehand and then omit the punct part of the argument in textcnt but then it doesn't use all kind of symbols such as & > or " to split, I have tried to modify the split argument but then it doesn't split the sentence at all or it keeps the symbols

Thank you

Comment: You mean you want `"[[:space:][:punct:][:digit:]]+"` to stop matching `'` chars?

Comment: I don't want the apostrophe ' to match, i want the function to remove and split by everything as it does by default except for the '

Comment: Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PCRE-based functions you need to use

```
split = "(?:(?!')[[:space:][:punct:][:digit:]])+|'\\B|\\B'"
```

Here,

- `(?:` - start of a container non-capturing group:
- `(?!')` - fail the match if the next char is a `'` char
- `[[:space:][:punct:][:digit:]]` - matches whitespace, punctuation or digit char
- `)+` - match one or more times (consecutively)
- `'\B` - a `'` char that is followed with either end of string or a non-word char
- `|` - or
- `\B'` - a `'` that is preceded with either start of string or a non-word char.

With `stringr` functions, you can use

```
split = "[[:space:][:punct:][:digit:]--[']]+|'\\B|\\B'"
```

Here, `[[:space:][:punct:][:digit:]--[']]` matches all characters matched by `[[:space:][:punct:][:digit:]]` except the `'` chars.

`stringr` ICU regex flavor [supports](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html#set-expressions-character-classes) [character class subtraction](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html) using this notation.

Comment: that shows thefollowing error Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  invalid regular expression '[[:space:][:punct:][:digit:]--[']]+'
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : PCRE pattern compilation error
 'invalid range in character class'
 at '--[']]+'

Comment: @AlbertoLlamas Then use a PCRE version.

Comment: this worked, thak you split = "(?:(?!')[[:space:][:punct:][:digit:]])+"

Comment: in more complex situations it kepps al ' and "" next to a word, do you think there's a way where it only keeps the ' that are between letters, for instance does keep I've but not  'I or "no" and so on, thank you

Comment: @AlbertoLlamas Try `"(?:(?!')[[:space:][:punct:][:digit:]])+|'\\B|\\B'"`